# Assigning dynamically values of string array to properties of an object in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

suppose a component named **searchBox** receives tow inputs: `@Input() titles: string[]` and `@Input() model: Object`, that the number of **titles** values is equal to number of **model** properties. **searchBox** generates input box to number of **titles** length, and gets searching subjects from user and push them into a string array named **titlesValues**. so, **searchBox** should assigns the values of **titlesValues** to **model** properties peer to peer and outputs the model via `@Output resultModel: Object`. I tried to access each **model** property dynamically for assigning to, therefore  I encoded this scenario in the following:

```
let i =0;
  Object.keys(this.model).forEach((key) => {
     this.model[key] = this.titlesValues[i];
   });
```

although I tested much statements and alternative codes to get desire result, but it gets bellow error:

> *Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Object'*.

how can I implement this scenario?
Best regards.

Comment: Can you create a Stackblitz example?

Comment: its difficult to understand, can you please create stackblitz example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To overcome the error, you can either explicitly define `model` to be of type `any`:

```ts
@Input() model: any;
```

**or**

define a new interface for the `model` and use it as:

```ts
interface Model {
    [index: string]: string;
}

@Input() model: Model;
```

Comment: If define input as interface  Model, when we send a model shuch as: myModel={name:'', job:'', addr:'', age:''} to searchBox, is there inconsistency at searchBox input or not?

Comment: Define< @Input() model: any > works good, but we want to avoid using type 'any' in our code.

Comment: If we define `Model` interface, then we need to be consistent across application when using it. The component sending data to SearchBox component should ensure correct data type is sent. Also you can tweak the interface definition as per your requirement.

Comment: We implemented searchBox reusable and use it in several component which contain object type models. Therefore, we want to receive result from searcBox as an object model and send it to backend for filtering and so on

Comment: There is one more alternative, but **it's not recommended** as it can cause some errors to be missed :) We can disable the `noImplicitAny` type-checking compiler option.

Answer (score 0):

try to change this:

```
@Input() titles: any[]
```

Comment: Suggestions to try something belong in comments.